# How to generate a city using custom models in a custom shape?

Tags: modeling, particles

So i need to create a custom medieval city. I have custom models for it already and the city needs to be in a specific shape, so not a square or circle. How can i generate the city within the shape with the custom models, without having the buildings colliding/overlapping?

Comment: please add some more screenshots how you did it. With geometry nodes? or hand-modeled? ...or? or provide your blend file...

Comment: I havn't done it, I'm trying to figure out how to do it. The buildings themselves are hand modeled.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be using geometry nodes.

So if you have the shape of your city:

[image]

you can add a geometry nodes modifier to that shape with this node setup:

[image]

You should put your buildings in the collection.

result:

[image]

yes, you have to "imagine" that the torus, cubes and cones are your building. By changing the distance min parameter, you can change the distance between your buildings.

> Note: this only works good, if the buildings have nearly the same
> size.

you could even add rivers or streets...where no building may be built.

Then the node setup looks like this:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much! I will try this out.

Comment: If the buildings have different sizes what would you recommend I do?

Comment: you could increase the "distance min" value. but this will of course increase the distance between all buildings,.

Comment: thanks again so much, ill try this out :)

Comment: Interesting city shape... I think medieval cities were usually round, because that's the optimal shape - the best area to the wall length... ;)

Comment: i am not a medieval city shape specialist...sorry :(